# jquery slide up function is not working when I click on the hover menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a hoverup menu. I tried writing a function in jquery, that on click of it, the hover menu should appear upwards. But, it's not happening. The click function is not working at all. on click of it, the hover menu should come out. Will somebody help me to troubleshoot this issue. Thank You.

My Code Below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image-container").click(function(){
    $(".dropup").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
 .application-container{
    position: relative;
  }
/* The dropup container */
.dropup{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: initial;
  display:none;
}

/* Dropup content (hidden by default) */
.dropup-content {
  width:100%;
  bottom:-100%;
  left:0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container application-container">
  <div class="row seven-rows">
    <div class="column text-center image-container">
      <img src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.png" width='69' height='61' alt="e-commerce">
      <p class="mt-2 text-custom">E Commerce</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropup">
      <div class="dropup-content pt-4 pb-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 ml-5">
            <h3> Innovative Omnichannel E-Commerce Solutions</h3>
            <p>AOE develops flexible and high-performance Enterprise E-Commerce portals. Our solutions digitize business processes and create efficient, profitable platforms for providers and customers.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom">E Commerce Solutions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You have this in your CSS which triggers before the jquery gets a chance `.image-container:hover + .dropup .dropup-content{
  display: block;
}`

Comment: I have removed that line of code. still its not working @mplungjan

Comment: You are dihing the content, you need to have display:none on the dropup only. Then you can do `$(".dropup").fadeIn();` - slideUp will HIDE `Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.`

Comment: still it's not working. I m following your method. Will you help me. @mplungjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove display:none from content
- Add diplay:none to dropup
- Use fadeIn

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image-container").click(function(){
    $(".dropup").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.application-container{
    position: relative;
  }
/* The dropup container */
.dropup{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: initial;
  display:none
}

/* Dropup content (hidden by default) */
.dropup-content {
  width:100%;
  bottom:-100%;
  left:0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container application-container">
  <div class="row seven-rows">
    <div class="column text-center image-container">
      <img src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.png" width='69' height='61' alt="e-commerce">
      <p class="mt-2 text-custom">E Commerce</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropup">
      <div class="dropup-content pt-4 pb-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 ml-5">
            <h3> Innovative Omnichannel E-Commerce Solutions</h3>
            <p>AOE develops flexible and high-performance Enterprise E-Commerce portals. Our solutions digitize business processes and create efficient, profitable platforms for providers and customers.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom">E Commerce Solutions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```